# "refers to a value, but is being used as a type here" error ONLY when interface is exported

Tags: typescript, interface

Why does adding an `export` cause consumers of a type to see type errors?

For example, the following does not error:

#### Before

**mod.d.ts**:

```
declare module "mod" {
    interface Blah { prop: number }
    const Blah: Blah;
    export default Blah;
}
```

**mod-usage.ts**:

```
import mod from "mod";

const example: mod = { prop: 3 }; // OK
```

================================

#### After

But when we add the `export` keyword on the interface, there is an error message at the usage site:

```
declare module "mod" {
    export interface Blah { prop: number } // only line that changed
    const Blah: Blah;
    export default Blah;
}
```

**mod-usage.ts**:

```
import mod from "mod";

//  error TS2749: 'mod' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here
const example: mod = { prop: 3 };.
```

Tested on TS 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 (same error in all versions)

Comment: If you export both `interface` and `const` it works, not sure if it's the intended behavior, but symbols for exported interface and local variable don't merge .

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Why? Is this intentional?
This behavior violates my expectation from plain ESM that export keyword and export declarations do the same thing.

Comment: The behavior is consistent between declarations and regular modules. I'm jus not sure it's intended as if it's the other way around (if the const is exported and the type is not  the merging still occurs) 

Comment: good point, seems to be backwards!